# CollapsingToolbar + MapView can not scroll up and down

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've faced the problem with CollapsingToolbar which has a MapView inside, here is my XML file.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/appbar_lay"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#ffffff"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways"
        app:titleEnabled="false">


  <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
          android:id="@+id/mapView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="300dp"
          android:clickable="true"
          app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
          android:focusable="true" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/main_activity_toolbar"
          android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

The problem is that when I try to scroll the map (up or down) I scroll Toolbar instead.

I can set up params for CoordinatorLayout to disable dragging.

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
  @Override
  public boolean canDrag(AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
    return false;
  }
});

params.setBehavior(behavior);
```

But is it possible to implement scrolling both for map and collapsing toolbar so CollapsingTolbar not to override scrolling event of MapView?

May be there is a way to scroll CollaspingToolbar only when user touch Toolbar and not the map?

Thanks for assistance.